# Crusty orange trails on my flower pots

Tags: orange

Can anyone explain what these trails are?  They seem to be harmless.  I clean them off but they come back overnight. I put a layer of leftover orchid potting soil on top of the soil of my potted geraniums.  This is maybe too much nitrogen for them, but could that be attracting whatever is causing these trails?

[image]

Comment: The picture isn't clear enough to tell -- what makes you think these marks are trails and not "impurities" in the clay leeching out between superficial cracks in the glaze? Much like hard water will leave white crust on an unfinished terra cotta pot?

Comment: Another interesting observation is that these marks do not appear to be on the lower part of the pot. It's tough to tell, but the marks also appear to be above the soil line.